# How to update firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I need update data into firebase using Firebase 3

Here is my code.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

    up()
  {
     var v=this.Editflat.value;
     firebase.database().ref('/flats').update(this.key,v).then(res=>
     {console.log("UPDATED",res)});

  }
```

I am getting this error

```
Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is what you want:

```
var v = this.Editflat.value;
firebase.database().ref('/flats/' + this.key).update(v).then(res => {
    console.log("UPDATED",res)
});
```

The variable `v` **should be an Object**.
You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.After I update to Firebase page redirection without push why?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean the page redirects without updating the Firebase data? You must post more code and edit your question details.

Comment: I called function using this button <button ion-button full type='submit'  (click)="up()">Update</button>.Update data into firebase successfully.But page redirect to rootpage.Why?.I hide the update code.does not page redirection.But I dont write any page redirect code.